# Description field for file field

Tags: views

I have a file field in a content type. I have enabled the description field for this field. How can I print this description field in twig???

I have a situation here I need to print description field only for one content in views page instead of all the contents on the same page.

For example:
First content has **Download**
Second content has **Download**
Third content has **field description**

Can I put some condition in twig or views field?

Comment: If you enable description field then the file(sample.txt) will be renamed with the description. My question is why do you need it to render in twig or view?

Comment: We are doing things via custom HTML in Twig, we need things to be done as per the client's requirements. He needs Download to be displayed on Anchor tags of PDF files but needs fields description for one PDF

Answer (score 0):

To use the description field directly in twig I found an easier way. Simply add the file field in Views, then rewrite the results and add the token for description and file. Now you can use the field directly into twig file.

Otherwise You might have to do good use of Kint or DSM to find out where does description field come up.